# In IIS 7, How Do I Redirect And Capture the Original URL?

Tags: iis, redirect

I have a peculiar CGI script written in Python; let's call it `peculiar.py`, I would like to "answer" any and all HTTP requests to a particular directory and anything under it, then capture the original URL from the environment variables.  The original URL is to be used later.  So far, I am trying a redirect to a default document, then calling up the environment variables for something relevant.  I haven't found anything relevant.

The concept walkthrough goes like:

1. User visits a URL like `http://site.domain.tld/videos/fun-stuff.html`.
2. User clicks on a link that says "Funny Link of the Day," which has an href to `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-source/2013-01-10/`.
3. IIS 7 receives request for `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-source/2013-01-10/`.
4. IIS 7 redirects to `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-target/`.
5. `Peculiar.py`, as the default document in `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-target/`, wakes up.
6. Peculiar.py finds that the original URL was `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-source/2013-01-10/`.
7. More processing after that.

My initial steps were to:

1. Make `peculiar.py` the default document in the "redirect-target" directory, so that `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-target/` would be answered by `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-target/peculiar.py`.  This works.
2. Use the HTTP Redirect feature, so `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-source/subdir1/item1.ext` would be redirected to `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-target/` and answered by `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-target/peculiar.py`.  This works.
3. Try to get the environment variables and find a good referrer.  (Or `referer`, as the grandfathered-in misspelling continues)

Right now, `peculiar.py` just grabs all of the environment variables and spits them out as HTML for me so I can examine them.

What I found, when I set up an HTTP Redirect using `Found (302)`, `Permanent (301)`, or even `Temporary (307)`, I could manage the redirect, but I could not get the original URL.  HTTP_REFERER isn't showing in the list of environment variables at all if I visit `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-source/subdir1/item1.ext`.  `HTTP_REFERER` does appear in the list of environment variables if I embed `http://site.domain.tld/redirect-source/subdir1/item1.ext` in a webpage as a hyperlink, but it only shows the original webpage.

It appears as if redirection just ... skips the referrer.  Is it because the referer is passed along from the client, not the server?

The background is that I'm building a script that spits out things like reference movies for Quicktime (binary file, constructed on the fly) and QTL files, both of which would vary based on the original URL called.  Yes, this is a lot of work to avoid querystrings in links.

Am I missing something obvious here?  Is redirection the wrong tool for answering all URLs under a particular directory?  Am I missing a setting in `web.config`, of which I am mostly ignorant?

I'm open to other approaches, so long as I can use Python and IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that it is undefined as whether or not to send the Referer header in response to a HTTP/301 or HTTP/302.  Remember that, in HTTP Redirection, the server sends the 301/302 with new Location header, but the *browser* is the thing that re-requests (and *it* decides whether or not to add the Location header).

Your best option might be pass the original value of Referer back in the 301/302 as a querystring parameter, e.g. (pseudo):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://site.domain.tld/redirect-target/?orig=http://site.domain.tld/redirect-source/2013-01-10/
```

and then capture the value of `orig` in your Python script.

You might need a custom ASP to do the actual redirection, using Response.Redirect(), rather than relying on the built-in IIS feature.

More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string